# Change an existing style's image colour property in Open Layers 3/4

Tags: openlayers

I wish to change the colour of a style in OL3.

A style can be created as follows:

```
styles = {
     icon: new ol.style.Style({
       image: new ol.style.Icon({
         anchor: [0.5, 1],
         src: search_icon_url,
         color: '#87CEFA'
       })
     })
};
```

Without creating a new style, I wish to progammatically adjust the colour of the existing icon.

I have tried

```
styles.icon.color = "#00FF00";
```

and

```
styles.icon.image_.color_ = [0,139,139,1];
```

Neither work, but neither throw an error.  The reason I wish to update the style is that any number of icons can be created, and i wish for the colour to be unique, so I need to adjust it on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Style Objects are immutable. You can use [StyleFunction](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.html#.StyleFunction) to accomplish this.

Comment: Well that explains the lack of effect with no error thrown.  Care to elaborate with a reference for your answer and perhaps an example of varying colour of image icon using the StyleFunction?